# Как установить ms office на Azure Cloud Services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, облако, office365

Я пишу сайт на которое пользователи загружают ms word документы, а сайт редактирует документы с помощью COM. Поэтому мне нужно чтобы на сервере (или облаке) был установлен ms word. Как я понимаю, чтобы пользоваться с ms office, не обязательно создать виртуальную машину.

Зарегистрировался на Azure по подписке Free Trial. Подписки на Office 365 у меня нет.

Создал Cloud Service. Как теперь установить ms office на облако? Если нужна подписка на Office 365, то могу ли я получить ее за счет 200$, которые дали из Azure Free Trial?

Благодарю за любые информации, хоть как то связанные с вопросом... а то я ничего не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Относительно установки чего-либо в облаке. Classic Cloud Service - это простая виртуалка с Windows 2016. Можно активировать удаленный доступ к инстансу и выполнить установку чего угодно. Не уверен, если получиться из WorkerRole получить доступ к окружению, но через COM объект должно получиться.

Comment: Classic Cloud Service - это набор виртуалок с автодеплоем на них package с ролями. Причем MS периодически обвновляет виртуалки, со сносом всего подряд. Т.е. все, что нужно для работы приложения, стоит ставить скриптами на старте роли, а не через remote desktop.